# How does one flatten an array of arrays in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following array:

```
val input = Array(Array(), Array(22,33), Array(), Array(77), Array(88,99))
```

It contains empty arrays. I want to get a flattened array without any empty arrays, so the output should be:

```
Array(22,33,77,88,99)
```

I tried the `flatten` function, but it seems to not work with the type of `Array[_ <: Int]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another way of writing:

```
input.flatMap(_.toList)
```

The empty arrays get converted to Nils and since it's a flatMap the Nils get flattened out

Answer (score 7):

Monads are your friends:

```
for { a <- input; b <- a.toList } yield b
```

Edit:
If you specify the type, `flatten` works fine

```
val input: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(), Array(22,33), Array(), Array(77), Array(88,99))
input.flatten
```

Comment: And even more concise `input.flatMap(_.toList)`

Answer (score 4):

It's inferring `Array[_ <: Int]` because some of the arrays are empty. Try this:

```
val input = Array(Array[Int](), Array(22,33), Array[Int](), Array(77), Array(88,99)).flatten
```

That ensures that the resulting type is `Array[Array[Int]]` which should be flattenable.

Comment: Actually all you need is type ascription: `val input:Array[Array[Int]] = ...`